# java 7 swing application rendering wrong colors on rhel7 machine

Tags: java-7, rhel7

I have a java swing application that is compiled with java 1.7_u60. It is launching fine on RHEL6.4 while the same when launched on the RHEL7 machine does not render properly.
In fact there is a black color everywhere and nothing is shown.

While launching application I also get the following Warning message.

WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported! This is an application bug!

I tried to update the GLX to 1.3 or higher but could not update this to higher version.

The output of glxinfo is as follows.

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: sahara:2
display: sahara:2 screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.2
server glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info,
GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_hyperpipe, GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier,
GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float,
GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context,
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.2
GLX extensions:
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_OML_swap_method,
GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object,
GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended,
GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer,
GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_texture,
GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend,
GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced,
GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions,
GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object,
GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex,
GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query,
GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multisample,
GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite,
GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_objects,
GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100,
GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing,
GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add,
GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage,
GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object,
GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_window_pos,
GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc,
GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr,
GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate,
GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract,
GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2,
GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object,
GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex,
GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs,
GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture,
GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp,
GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine,
GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias,
GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object,
GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback,
GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip,
GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate,
GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba,
GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_blend_square,
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent,
GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_primitive_restart,
GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4,
GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format,
GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp,
GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

2 GLX Visuals
visual x bf lv rg d st colorbuffer sr ax dp st accumbuffer ms cav
id dep cl sp sz l ci b ro r g b a F gb bf th cl r g b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x027 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None

2 GLXFBConfigs:
visual x bf lv rg d st colorbuffer sr ax dp st accumbuffer ms cav
id dep cl sp sz l ci b ro r g b a F gb bf th cl r g b a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x023 24 tc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
0x027 24 dc 0 24 0 r y . 8 8 8 0 . . 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 None
```

I would love to have your help.

Thanks a ton

Ankit

Comment: I am logged on to the RHEL machine via GoGlobal.

Comment: I removed the java.2d.opengl=true  which was being passed to the JRE at run time ans it did work on RHEL7.